# Android VideoView not call onSurfaceCreated until click to it

Tags: android, android-fragments, surfaceview, android-videoview

I am use VideoView to play mp4 and m3u8 files. I am load VideoView in a fragment and put it in a Activity, here is a code load video url in the fragment:

```
if(currentPossition == 0 || isCompleted) {
        Uri path = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
        videoView.setVideoURI(path);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        controller.setAnchorView(videoView);
        controller.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(controller);
    }else{
        videoView.seekTo(currentPossition);
        videoView.start();
    }
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {                 
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```

And in class VideoView, I have found a callback `SurfaceHolder.Callback mSHCallback` and function `surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)` called when surface created on the first times. So, my video play in the first times, problems is when I am destroy fragment (`surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)` called and mSurfaceHolder = null) and replace again in the getSupportFragmentManager, the callback `SurfaceHolder.Callback` not called until I am touch in VideoVideo or click a button control in the Activity. Any help this problems ?